# Rescale ylimits density plot ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I made a Boxplot with connected data and I am trying to add a density plot. The problem is that the density plot seems to be on a different scale.

This is what the plot looks like[image]

It's clear that the density plots should have limits from 0 to somewhere around 300.

This is my datasets reproduced with dput:

```
structure(list(progNum = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L), Condition = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Sum_noaction", "Sum_csm"), class = "factor"), 
    nRes = c(97.5, 96.5, 97.5, 94, 97, 89.5, 96.5, 245.5, 232.5, 
    233.5, 168.5, 222.5, 232.5, 195.5, 241.5, 201, 215.5, 189, 
    197.5, 238.5, 231, 219, 217.5, 225.5, 199.5, 299, 282, 294, 
    314, 238, 293, 289, 299.5, 252, 297.5, 278.5, 256.5, 297.5, 
    276.5, 214.5, 188, 217.5, 92.5, 98, 98.5, 89, 97, 92.5, 97, 
    247, 218.5, 227, 175.5, 227.5, 232, 187, 240.5, 201.5, 221.5, 
    86.5, 197.5, 232.5, 231.5, 224.5, 212, 220.5, 197.5, 309, 
    275, 287.5, 310.5, 226, 298, 283, 223, 50, 294.5, 293, 260.5, 
    301, 281.5, 215.5, 189.5, 216.5), pairings = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
    29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
    41L, 42L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
    25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
    37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L)), row.names = c(NA, -84L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my code so far:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(psych)
library(tidyr)
library(patchwork)
###################################################################################################
###                          Setup a theme for Boxplots
###################################################################################################
# define theme to make plots look pretty
plotThemeBoxplots = theme(
  text = element_text(size = 18),
  axis.title.x=element_blank(),
  # axis.text.x=element_blank(),
  axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 18),
  axis.text = element_text(size = 18),
  # axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5),
  legend.title=element_text(size=18),
  legend.text=element_text(size=18),
  legend.position = "none",
  plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold", size = 16),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'black', size=1, linetype='solid'),
  axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black', size=1, linetype='solid'))


###################################################################################################
#                  CONNECTED BOXPLOTS DATA Action Vs CS- N RES
###################################################################################################
#boxplotData = data %>% 
  #dplyr::select(progNum, Sum_noaction, Sum_csm) %>% 
  #melt(id.vars = c("progNum"), measure.vars = c("Sum_noaction", "Sum_csm"),
       #variable.name = "Var", value.name = "nRes")


pairings = c(c(1:42), c(1:42))
boxplotData$pairings = pairings

names(boxplotData)[2] = "Condition"
names(boxplotData)[3] = "nRes"

connected_dots_03 = boxplotData %>%
  ggplot(aes(Condition, nRes, fill=Condition)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_line(aes(group=pairings), position = position_dodge(0.2)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=Condition,group=pairings),size=2,shape=21, position = position_dodge(0.2)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Condition",labels=c("No Action", "CS-"),
                    values=c("hotpink1", "green"))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, 600, by = 100),1), limits = c(0, 600))+
  plotThemeBoxplots+
  ylab("Number of Responses")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c('No Action', 'CS-'))

connected_dots_03

densConnectdBox <- ggplot(boxplotData, aes(x = nRes, fill=Condition)) + 
  geom_density(alpha = .5, colour = NA) + # , fill="turquoise1"
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("hotpink1", "green"))
 

connected_dots_03 + densConnectdBox + 
  plot_layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 1, widths = c(2, 0.5), heights = c(1, 4))
```

I've tried several things such as addying:

```
 coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 600))
```

Nothing seems to work...

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try adding `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, 600, by = 100),1), limits = c(0, 600))` before `coord_flip()`  when generating you density plot

Comment: Thank you SO much, it worked! I had tried scale_x_continuous but I was doing something wrong...Really appreciate!

Comment: Can one of you put this as an answer so that this question stops appearing in the "Unanswered" category?

Comment: @L-- I think thebest thing would be if you put it as an answer so you can get the deserved credit for it, and I'll be happy to accept it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the limits of the `x` axis of the density plot using the `scale_x_continuous` function such that it matches the limits of the other plot.

You can do it when you generate `densConnectdBox` or even afterwards as follows:

```
connected_dots_03 + 
  (densConnectdBox + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 600))) + 
  plot_layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 1, widths = c(2, 0.5), heights = c(1, 4))
```

[image]